# Group data by field from related table

Tags: laravel

**I have a tables:**

Event[id, 'name', 'areTicketsGenerated'],

Ticket ['id', event_id', 'seat_price_id', 'isAvailable'],

SeatPrice['id', 'price_zone_id'].

I need to receive all events. In each event I need to count available tickets grouped by 'price_zone_id'.

My query is next:

```
$events = Event::with([
    'tickets',
    'tickets.seatPrice',
  ])->where('areTicketsGenerated', true)
  ->get();
foreach($events as $event) {
   $ticketsCount = $event->tickets->where('isAvailable', true) ...
}
```

But I only recieved all available tickets.

How can I group by 'price_zone_id'?

For example:

Event1

Price Zone 1 - 10 tickets;

Price Zone 2 - 50 tickets.

Event2

Price Zone 4 - 20 tickets;

Price Zone 5 - 25 tickets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the desired required results:

```
$data = Event::join('Ticket','Event.id','Ticket.event_id')
    ->join('SeatPrice','Ticket.seat_price_id','SeatPrice.id')
    ->select('Event.id as id','price_zone_id',DB::raw('count(Ticket.*) as Total'))
    ->where('isAvailable', true)
    ->groupby('Event.id','price_zone_id')
    ->get();

$events = $data->groupBy('id')->toarray();
```

Now in your Blade you should be able to:

```
@foreach($events as $key => $event)
   {{$key}}
   @foreach($event as $item)
      {{$item['price_zone_id']}} - {{$item['Total']}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, but in query result I received something next:
Event1 - 
Price Zone 1 - 10 tickets;
Event2 - 
Price Zone 4 - 20 tickets;

Comment: I don't understand, what did you get?

Comment: I mean that in rezult your query I received next: event 1 - count price_zone_1 in all events.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand

Comment: Event 1 - get all price zones in this event. Event 2 - get all price zones in this event, etc.

Comment: Your request return next: Event 1 - get one price zone from all events. Event 2 - get one price zone from all events, etc. –

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Can you accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$events = Event::with([
    'tickets',
    'tickets.seatPrice' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('price_zone_id');
    }])
  ->where('areTicketsGenerated', true)
  ->get();
```

**Updated Answer**

Also use of fluent query

```
use DB;

$events = DB::table('events')
          ->join('tickets', 'tickets.event_id', '=', 'events.id') 
          ->leftJoin('seat_price', 'tickets.seat_price_id', '=', 'seat_price.id')
          ->where('events.areTicketsGenerated',true)
          ->groupBy('seat_price.price_zone_id')
          ->get();
```

Comment: The connection between ticket and seatPrice is lost, expect first element in the tickets list

Comment: And tickets are not grouped

Comment: @VladimirIshchenko: Can i use fluent query?

Comment: In query rezult I have only recieved events without prices(